# WearableCalendarContract query "Sort order is not supported" error

Tags: android, wear-os, calendarcontract

I'm getting a `Sort order is not supported` error when trying to apply a sort order to my query. The query runs just fine if the sort order is null. Can anyone help me here? Code is below:

```
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Uri.Builder builder = WearableCalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
            ContentUris.appendId(builder, currentTime);
            ContentUris.appendId(builder, currentTime + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);

            final String[] PROJECTION = {
                    CalendarContract.Calendars._ID, // 0
                    CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN, // 1
                    CalendarContract.Instances.END, // 2
                    CalendarContract.Events.DISPLAY_COLOR, // 3
                    CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, // 4
                    CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY // 5
            };

            final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                    .query(builder.build(),
                            PROJECTION,
                            null, // selection (all)
                            null, // selection args
                            CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN + " ASC"); // order
```

Comment: The error seems pretty self explanatory - what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Nothing I have tried as a sort order works. Additionally when searching for solutions to this, every example I found of working queries had the same thing or similar as their sort order.

I feel like something else must be wrong here; or that perhaps querying WearableCalendarContract works differently somehow, since all the examples I found were actually just looking at CalendarContract. Documentation was unhelpful here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as the error message says, `WearableCalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI` does not support sorting. It is a completely separate implementation from `CalendarContract`, even though it shares the same fields.

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. I was assuming the error meant that I had the wrong thing in the sort order - it hadn't occurred to me that it was trying to tell me sort orders aren't supported at all. Thanks!